# How do I sort an array of int, doubles and negative numbers in 3 different new arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have no idea in how to sort the array into three separate arrays of positive ints, positive doubles, and all negatives.

```
var numbers: [Any] = [4,3.9,-23,3,7.6,-51,75.3]
```

--> here would have an if to filter the positives from negatives, and printing them

```
//-23 -51
```

-->here a filter to print the remaining INTs

```
//4 3
```

--> here a filter to print the remaining DOUBLES

```
//3.9 7.6 75.3
```

Comment: You can't have such array, is it an array of numeric strings? Show us your input (array) and what you have tried and want to accomplish

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you have used so far, along with some sample input-output pairs. How are you storing the numbers? Is the array defined as `Array<Any>`?

Comment: By default, if you put `Int` `Double` in the same array, Swift with infer that it's an array of Doubles. If the array is of type `Any` it's possible, but may require more work to filter and split the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
//postive ints

let one = 1
let two = 2
let seven = 7
let ninetyThree = 93

//Negative ints

let minusOne =          -1
let minusTwo =          -2
let minusSeven =        -7
let minusNinetyThree =  -93

//Doubles

let onePointSeven = 1.7
let pi = Double.pi
let sqareRootOfTwo = sqrt(2)
let minusTwentyPointThree = -20.3

//Create an array containing a mixture of types
let mixedArray: [Any] = [
one,
sqareRootOfTwo,
minusTwo,
seven,
pi,
minusTwo,
minusSeven,
minusOne,
minusNinetyThree,
two,
ninetyThree,
minusTwentyPointThree,
onePointSeven,
]


//Filter the array to just the positive Ints
let positiveInts = (mixedArray.filter {
    guard let int = $0 as? Int else { return false }
    return int >= 0
    } as! [Int])         //Cast it to type [Int]
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }  //Sort it into numeric order
print("positiveInts = \(positiveInts)")

//Filter the array to just the negative Ints
let negativeInts = (mixedArray.filter {
    guard let int = $0 as? Int else { return false }
    return int < 0
    } as! [Int])         //Cast it to type [Int]
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }  //Sort it into numeric order
print("negativeInts = \(negativeInts)")

//Filter the array to just the Doubles
let doubles = (mixedArray.filter {
    return $0 is Double
    } as! [Double])         //Cast it to type [Double]
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }     //Sort it into numeric order
print("doubes = \(doubles)")
```

And the output is:

```
positiveInts = [1, 2, 7, 93]
negativeInts = [-93, -7, -2, -2, -1]
doubes = [-20.300000000000001, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7, 3.1415926535897931]
```

Comment: Is that what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
let array: [Double] = [-2.5, -1, 0, 3, 5.2]

let negatives = array.filter { $0 < 0 }
let positiveDoubles = array.filter { $0 > 0 }
let positiveInts = positiveDoubles.filter { $0.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In getting positive a Int from a Double, wouldn't it also be useful to round up or down positiveDoubles?

```
positiveInts = positiveDoubles.compactMap{ Int(round(Double($0))) }
```